# How to sleep in for loop

Tags: javascript, delay

How do I make a 5 second delay in following code before moving to the next input element:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('_aj7');
for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    inputs[i].click();
}
```

Comment: There is no "sleep" in JavaScript. It's a single-threaded execution that is shared with everything else on the page. You don't get to suspend it. If you want a timeout use [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to introduce a delay between actions, you need to use something like [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout). For example:

```
function f() {
  inputs[i].click();
  if (++i < inputs.length) {
    setTimeout(f, 5000);
  }
}

var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('_aj7');
var i = 0;
if (i < inputs.length) {
  f();
}
```

Comment: thanks ! its work :D